# How estimate recursive `aws s3 ls` costs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Suppose I have 10,000 files in AWS S3 bucket each placed in subdirectory `/year/month/day/hour/file`

A `LIST` request can return up to 1000 objects.

Will recursive list on this bucket be billed as 10 `LIST` operations or 10,000 operations + `LIST` operations for root directories.

Answer (score 8):

`LIST` requests are charged at `$0.005 per 1000 requests` so this shouldn't be a big impact on your charges.

If you are frequently listing large buckets, you might consider using [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html). It can provide a daily CSV file with a listing of all objects in the bucket, including metadata.